# How would I get the row wise count of a string match and add it as a new column in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Here is my dataframe:

```
  val new_df = Seq(("mike","A","B","B","C","A"),
    ("bob","A","A","B","A","C")).toDF("name","math","science","english","history","art")
```

and here is the resultant dataframe I'm trying to produce:

```
  val new_df2 = Seq(("mike","A","B","B","C","A",2,2,1),
    ("bob","A","A","B","A","C",3,1,1)).toDF("name","math","science","english","history","art","A_count","B_count","C_count")
```

Here are before and after snapshots in tabular view:

[image]

[image]

So I want to add a column that gets the count of A's (or any string match) of every row. How would I go about this? I know something using withColumn will work but I'm not sure how to string match over a row.

Thanks so much and have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved dynamically in one pass by flat-mapping over the rows then columns of the `Dataframe` and then doing a `.pivot().count()` on the result.

```
val grades = Array[String]("A", "B", "C")
val cols = new_df.columns
val gcount = new_df.flatMap( row => {
    val name = row.getAs[String]("name")
    cols.flatMap( c => {
        val grade = row.getAs[String](c)
        if (grades.contains(grade)) {
            Some(name, grade)    
        } else {
            None
        }
    })
}).toDF("name", "grade")
  .groupBy("name")
  .pivot("grade")
  .count()
  .withColumnRenamed("A", "A_count")
  .withColumnRenamed("B", "B_count")
  .withColumnRenamed("C", "C_count")

new_df.join(gcount, "name").show()
```

This results in:

```
+----+----+-------+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+-------+
|name|math|science|english|history|art|A_count|B_count|C_count|
+----+----+-------+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+-------+
|mike|   A|      B|      B|      C|  A|      2|      2|      1|
| bob|   A|      A|      B|      A|  C|      3|      1|      1|
+----+----+-------+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+-------+
```

--- Edit

I can go through each of the main steps, and explain what they do:

```
val gcount = new_df.flatMap( row => {
    val name = row.getAs[String]("name")
    cols.flatMap( c => {
        val grade = row.getAs[String](c)
        if (grades.contains(grade)) {
            Some(name, grade)    
        } else {
            None
        }
    })
}).toDF("name", "grade")
```

A `.flatmap()` is like a `.map()`, except that instead of a 1:1 ratio of input records to output records, it's a 1:n ratio. In other words, it can emit 0 or more records for each record it processes. In this case, we are iterating through each row, and then iterating through each column to emit a record for each grade, for each person (as long as the cell's value exists in our initial array of interesting grades). The `.toDF()` method simply converts our resulting `Dataset[(String, String)]` back into a `Dataframe`. This block of code results in a `Dataframe` that looks like this:

```
+----+-----+
|name|grade|
+----+-----+
|mike|    A|
|mike|    B|
|mike|    B|
|mike|    C|
|mike|    A|
| bob|    A|
| bob|    A|
| bob|    B|
| bob|    A|
| bob|    C|
+----+-----+
```

With that intermediate `Dataframe` We can do a

```
groupBy("name").pivot("grade").count()
```

The `groupBy()` creates groups of records by the value contained in the provided column. And then, `.pivot()` will take the distinct values within it's provided column and create a new column for each of them. Finally, the `.count()` method determines how to aggregate the values of the distinct column groups.

The `.withColumnRenamed()` methods were there just to make the final `Dataframe` "look" just like the one you requested by actually renaming columns (since the actual previous grade values became the column names). That would have been better solved by changing `Some(name, grade)` to `Some(name, grade+"_count")` to avoid the static column renaming.

Regarding the CSV error you are getting, I'd have to see the actual code and the CSV header to understand what could be causing that.

--- Alternate Solution

I also worked up a hacky alternate solution that requires the columns in your source `Dataframe` be fixed, and may not be the most efficient thing. It's mostly unrelated to the better solution above, but I'm providing it in case it's helpful:

```
var df = new_df
val grades = Array[String]("A", "B", "C")

grades.foreach(g => {
    df = df.withColumn(g +"_count", ($"math" === lit(g)).cast("Int") + ($"science" === lit(g)).cast("Int") + ($"english" === lit(g)).cast("Int") + ($"history" === lit(g)).cast("Int") + ($"art" === lit(g)).cast("Int"))
})
```

Again, it's a hacky solution, but could work for a small number of "grades", a fixed column set, and if you don't care as much about efficiency.

Comment: Do you have a step by step solution that would be easier to understand and break into smaller steps? Your code works perfectly on this sample dataframe, but when I apply it to my huge dataframe I'm getting errors that the CSV header doesn't conform to the schema. And yeah I double checked that I changed all the variable names appropriately etc.

Comment: I've added some explanation of the main steps after the "--- Edit".

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is with Spark SQL. Whilst you can solve this with flatMap, it's much slower, and it's better to try and do it all just in-line! I've written this so you can easily extend to more grades, and there's a bit less boiler plate.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

def colIsGrade(col:Column, grade:String) = when(col === lit(grade), lit(1)).otherwise(lit(0))

def countOccurenceOf(grade:String) = (List($"math", $"science", $"english", $"history", $"art").foldLeft(lit(0)) {
  case (count, subject) => colIsGrade(subject, grade) + count
}).as(s"${grade}_count")

val grades = List("A","B","C","D","E","F")
val gradesColumnStatement = grades.map(countOccurenceOf)

new_df.select(col("*") +: gradesColumnStatement :_*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Spark-sql solution using the stack() function. Since the number of columns other than "name" is 5, the count is assumed as such.

```
val new_df = Seq(("mike","A","B","B","C","A"),
    ("bob","A","A","B","A","C")).toDF("name","math","science","english","history","art")

new_df.show(false)

val new_df2 = Seq(("mike","A","B","B","C","A",2,2,1),
    ("bob","A","A","B","A","C",3,1,1)).toDF("name","math","science","english","history","art","A_count","B_count","C_count")

new_df2.show(false)

new_df.createOrReplaceTempView("grade")
val stack_map = new_df.columns.filter( x => x != "name").map( x => x + ",'"+x+"'"  ).mkString(",")
val res1 = spark.sql(s"""
with t1 ( select * from grade),
    t2 (select name, stack(5,${stack_map}) (grade,subject) from t1)
select * from t2
""").groupBy("name").pivot("grade").count


new_df.alias("t1").join(res1.alias("t2"),expr(" t1.name = t2.name "))
  .withColumnRenamed("A", "A_count")
  .withColumnRenamed("B", "B_count")
  .withColumnRenamed("C", "C_count")
  .show(false)

+----+----+-------+-------+-------+---+----+-------+-------+-------+
|name|math|science|english|history|art|name|A_count|B_count|C_count|
+----+----+-------+-------+-------+---+----+-------+-------+-------+
|mike|A   |B      |B      |C      |A  |mike|2      |2      |1      |
|bob |A   |A      |B      |A      |C  |bob |3      |1      |1      |
+----+----+-------+-------+-------+---+----+-------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Meta-programming solution:

```
new_df.createOrReplaceTempView("grade")

val grade_cols = new_df.columns.filter( x => x != "name")

val grade_all = grade_cols.map( c => collect_set(col(c)).as(c+"_set"))

val df2 = new_df.groupBy().agg(grade_all.head, grade_all:_*)

df2.show(false)

df2.withColumn("all", df2.columns.map(c => col(c) ).reduce{ (x,y) => concat(x,y) }).show(false)

//+--------+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------+---------------------------+
//|math_set|math_set|science_set|english_set|history_set|art_set|all                        |
//+--------+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------+---------------------------+
//|[A]     |[A]     |[B, A]     |[B]        |[C, A]     |[C, A] |[A, A, B, A, B, C, A, C, A]|
//+--------+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------+---------------------------+

val df3 = df2.withColumn("all", df2.columns.map(c => col(c) ).reduce{ (x,y) => concat(x,y) }).withColumn("all2",expr("array_distinct(all)"))

val grades_arr = df3.select("all2").as[(Array[String])].first

val map_grades = grades_arr.map( g => { val p = grade_cols.map( c => expr(s" case when ${c}='${g}' then 1 else 0 end ") ).reduce(_+_); (g,p) } ).toMap

val df4 = grades_arr.foldLeft(new_df){ (acc,x) => acc.withColumn(x+"_count",map_grades(x)) }

df4.show(false)
```

Results:

```
+----+----+-------+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+-------+
|name|math|science|english|history|art|A_count|B_count|C_count|
+----+----+-------+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+-------+
|mike|A   |B      |B      |C      |A  |2      |2      |1      |
|bob |A   |A      |B      |A      |C  |3      |1      |1      |
+----+----+-------+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+-------+
```